# JS using partially parametrized function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

I'm very new to JS, I've tried code below :

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array, threshold) {
  return (element >= threshold);
}
[1, 2, 3].every(isBigEnough(threshold=0)
```

I thought it doesn't work because `prototype` (in `Array.prototype.filter()`) does not contain threshold, so it is types mismatch, but we can't define like this :
    `isBiggerThenZero = isBigEnough(threshold=0)`
so is there nice workaround for this case ?

Comment: in the function definition, do something like this function isBigEnough(element, index, array, threshold=0)

Comment: and then do not pass last parameter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `[1, 2, 3].every(isBigEnough(0))`. It:

- Calls `isBigEnough` that returns `false`.
- Executes `[1, 2, 3].every(false)`. Where `false` is not a function. SO it gives you an error.

You can use a closure that binds threshold value to the returned function:

```js
function isBigEnough(threshold) {
  return function(element, index, array) {
     return (element >= threshold);
  }
}
[1, 2, 3].every(isBigEnough(0))
```

Comment: One-argument-per-function is called currying and this partially curried function demonstrates its usefulness

Comment: this is great solution

Answer (score 1):

Default parameters must be in the function declaration, e.g:

```
function isBigEnough(element, index, array, threshold=0) {
  return (element >= threshold);
}
[1, 2, 3].every(isBigEnough);
```

However, now its difficult to pass threshold:

```
[1,2,3].every((...a)=>isBigEnough(...a,2));
```

So you could rather do:

```
function isBigEnough(threshold=0,element, index, array) {
 return (element >= threshold);
}
[1, 2, 3].every(isBigEnough.bind(null,5));//threshold=5
```